Could a gas giant have terrestrial planets for trojans?
Please lets take into account this hypothetical scenario:
In a solar system with an F5V main sequence star at its center a gas giant of about 7 Jupiter Masses leaves the "frost-zone" and migrates in the habitable zone, eventually entering a stable orbit at about 2.14 AUs.
Would it be realistic for the gas giant to capture 1 or even 2 mercury-like objects within it's torjan belts?
Edit* To clarify, I meant 2 objects as in one per trojan belt, not 2 in the same trojan belt.

@ScienceSnake I don't know about the bombardment problem... Do the trojans really collect new matter that often? By the time the "trojan planet" is cool enough to be past the Hadean era, I'm sure it would have either ejected or absorbed all the available trojan matter, and I thought the trojan populations were pretty stable...

https://www.livescience.com/space/exoplanets/1st-known-trojan-planets-discovered-locked-in-the-exact-same-orbit-around-a-star https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-orbital_configuration#Trojan_planets

Astrophysicist Sean Raymond believes that a gas giant could possibly have terrestrial planets in the Trojan positions.
He has a blog called Planetplanet.
https://planetplanet.net/about/
And one of the sections of Planetplanet is called The Ultimate Solar System.  In it Raymond tries to design plausible solar systems which have as many habitable planets as possible.
https://planetplanet.net/the-ultimate-solar-system/
In part 5 his ultimate solar system 2 has four planetary orbits in the habitable zone of the star.  Each orbit has one gas giant planet, each having five moons large enough to be habitable, for a total of 20 habitable worlds.  And each orbit has a terrestrial planet in the L4 and L5 trojan positions.  And each trojan planet is binary, so that makes 16 more potentially habitable worlds for a total of 36.
https://planetplanet.net/2014/05/23/building-the-ultimate-solar-system-part-5-putting-the-pieces-together/
Thus he seems to believe that gas giant planets can have terrestrial planets in their trojan positions.
If you are asking because you are interested in writing a story set in such a star system, you should know that there is a site called Worldbulding Stack Exchange for these types of questions.
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Hmmm an excellent answer I gotta say, I'll admit it is for writing a story but at the same time I was genuinely curious about the prospect of trojian orbits being occupied by plantes. I'll check the links if they are satisfying I'll consider the question closed
